# The scope from makePtr

Tags: opencv

which is the scope of makePtr from  Opencv?
I got the error, that makePtr is not declared in this scope.

I have include the libraries core.hpp, imgprog.hpp. ml.hpp,

ok... so i'm using C++ with netbeans and I have a code how I can detect a text in an image. its wiht the algorithm from Neumann and Matas

An example is: I have the class:

```
class CV_EXPORTS ERClassifierNM2 : public ERFIlter::Callback{
public:
   ERClassifierNM2 (const string& filename);
   ~ERClassifierNM2;
   double eval (const ERStat& stat);
private:
 CvBoost boost;

Ptr<ERFilter::Callback> loadClassifierNM2(const string& filename){
 return makePtr<ERClassifierNM2> (filename); }
```

Now I get the messages: makePtr is not declared in this scope and expected primary expression before ">" token

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should post the full error and the lines of code (and some surrounding for context). You should also tag what language you are using (C++?).

Answer (score 3):

For everybody who is interested in the solution.

You can solve this problem,when you writes

`Ptr<ERFilterNM2> (new ERFilterNM2 (filename);`

instead of

`makePtr<ERClassifierNM2> (filename);`

This is only another syntax  and you don't need makePtr any more :)